# Laravel Validation - How to use custom validation without field

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 7, and I want to return an error if my Model has a relationship or not.

This error doesn't rely on a field, so I want to add a rule but without field.

I tried :

```
$rules [] = [
            'address' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($parking) {
                if (! $parking or ! $parking->parkingAddress()->count()) {
                    $fail("You must fill address before !");
                }
            }
        ];
```

Or :

```
$rules [] = function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($parking) {
                if (! $parking or ! $parking->parkingAddress()->count()) {
                    $fail("You must fill address before !");
                }
            };
```

But it doesn't throw the error. How I can return the error ?

Comment: Can you provide any additional information about how your relationship is defined? I assume there is some sort of pivot table involved if you don't have direct access to a `parking_id` field. It would also be handy to know whether these rules are part of a Controller method or a Form Request object. How is the `$parking` variable being set?

Comment: My problem is not about my logic, but more about how I can return the error

Comment: It's more for context than expecting there to be a logic error. If you are using a `Validator` inside a controller then you can check the attached `MessageBag` to see whether your closure has written an error to it ...

Comment: you could make your own rule and access the `MessageBag` as @Spholt says [create rules](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules), [error bag](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#working-with-error-messages)